# Synology DSM 6.1 virtual host on photo station

Tags: reverse-proxy, virtualhost, synology

I've got photo station package running (fine) on a Synology DSM 6.1 server.
I also got a domain name "mydomain.com" pointing to this server.

http://photo.mydomain.com/photo works fine, but how can I get ride of the trailling "/photo" in the URL?

I've found some way telling how to do so on internet (by tweaking system file with ssh command). But these "option" is removed each time photo station, web station or DSM are updated !!!

Not really what I expect from something supposed to be never touched once installed and (properly) configured...

How can I get a **persistent** solution for this?

Comment: You ever get an answer to this?  Trying to do this with two separate docker containers...

Comment: I never get any answer : I have replaced Photo Station by Moment. http://photo.mydomain.com works fine with it...